# Baking Ambient maps, black noise?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I have been struggling a lot lately with AO map baking, and just ran into a new problem! I'm currently trying to bake out occlusion maps for a few rocks, been doing it to several different ones with little problem, but just finished rendering a few out from a few very highpoly rocks and get weird black "pixelspots" Not sure what I'm doing wrong, i am on highest sampling possible, and i tried raising the "bias" which helped, but as it decreases the amount of shadow aswell its not quite the solution i wanna go with!

Has anyone bumped into this, and got a solution for it?

[image: A zoomed in picture of the noise.]

Comment: No, I have not had this issue before

Comment: Could you show a bit of your scene&setup? Or upload a portion of the file? Maybe it could be helpful in guessing where the problem cames from. Does it happens even if you append the objects in another file? Does it happens to "new objects" too?

Comment: Ye, haha that was actually me! but this isn't the same problem as far as I can tell, but ill upload a portion of the file! And I'm doing the multires method when trying to bake the AOMAP! https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By4AwCMVSPt4MEZkMDNzXzBHdG8/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution for this baking senario:

**Note** The result are correct, you will need deep crevices to create really
dark shadows or details. If you need more shadows on your ambient map consider using a 2D image editor like photoshop or Gimp to up the levels.

1. Change your baking bias from 0.001 to 0.01

[image]

Comment: Oh okay, well i did do that before, and it did solve it but it removed a lot of the shadows as well! But i guess ill just use PS to increase the amount of shadows as you said!